# how to iterate a function over multiple lists?

Tags: python

I have the following function:

```
def calc(X: float, Y: float, z: float) -> dict:
    n1 = X*Y
    n2 = Y*z
    n3 = z**2
    return {"c": n1, "d" : n2, "e" : n3}
```

I can take a list such as [10,10,20] and input it into the function using the *args approach:

```
list_1 = [10,10,20]
calc(*list_1)

#results
{'c' : 100, 'd': 200, 'e': 400}
```

However, let's assume I want to pass an array or multiple lists into the function, such as:

```
list_2 = [[10,10,20],
          [20,25,30],
          [35,40,45]]
```

where I want the function to iterate over each individual list.

I have thought about using a loop, but cannot get how to iterate over each aspect of the multi-dimensional list.

I have tried potentially using the index by doing the following:

```
for x in len(list_2):
      call(*list_2[x])
```

but I get the following error:

```
'int' object is not ierable
```

Ideally, I would like this to be vectorized and avoid using loops, but any input or direction is much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that you cannot avoid looping over the list, since you have to extract each sublist and pass it to the function as argument.

Now you can iterate over the 2D list, and pass each sublist as an argument, and then collect the results in a list

```
def calc(X: float, Y: float, z: float) -> dict:
    n1 = X*Y
    n2 = Y*z
    n3 = z**2
    return {"c": n1, "d" : n2, "e" : n3}


list_2 = [[10,10,20],
          [20,25,30],
          [35,40,45]]

#Iterate over the sublists, pass each sublist to the function, and collect its result
res = [calc(*li) for li in list_2]

print(res)
```

Or you can use a [map](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) which is equivalent to the list-comprehension defined above

```
#Pass each sublist to the function by unpacking the list of lists, and collect its result
res = list(map(calc, *list_2))
```

The output will be same in both cases

```
[{'c': 100, 'd': 200, 'e': 400}, 
{'c': 500, 'd': 750, 'e': 900}, 
{'c': 1400, 'd': 1800, 'e': 2025}]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [itertools.starmap](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.starmap):

```
import itertools

result = itertools.starmap(call, list_2)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could also pass [unpacked](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists) `list_2` into [`map()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) function.

**Code:**

```
def calc(x: float, y: float, z: float) -> dict:
    n1 = x*y
    n2 = y*z
    n3 = z**2
    return {"c": n1, "d": n2, "e": n3}


list_2 = [[10, 10, 20], [20, 25, 30], [35, 40, 45]]

result = list(map(calc, *list_2))
```

**Output:**

```
[{'c': 200, 'd': 700, 'e': 1225}, {'c': 250, 'd': 1000, 'e': 1600}, {'c': 600, 'd': 1350, 'e': 2025}]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `map` function (https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#map), so you can do:

```py
print(list(map(calc, *list_2)))
```

and the output will be:

```py
[{'c': 200, 'd': 700, 'e': 1225}, {'c': 250, 'd': 1000, 'e': 1600}, {'c': 600, 'd
': 1350, 'e': 2025}]
```

Comment: Unfortunately, your answer duplicates mine, which have been posted a bit earlier.

Comment: I saw that after posting my answer :(, at the time I was writing it there wasn't any answer in the thread